# Java Multi-thread TCP Socket - Receive message from clients until they become disconnected

Tags: java, c#, multithreading, sockets, tcp

I have the below code to accept multiple client from my Java Server.

```
private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {
        int count = 0;
        String error_message = null;
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try{
                serverSocket = new ServerSocket(theSocketServerPORT);
                while (true){
                    final Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    count++;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"New Client with IP: " + socket.getInetAddress() + " and PORT: " + socket.getPort(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                    SocketServerListenToMessage socketServerListenToMessage = new SocketServerListenToMessage(socket); 
                    socketServerListenToMessage.run();// Start to Receive now
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("IO ERROR",e.toString());
                error_message = "IO ERROR";
            }catch (Exception e){

                Log.e("EX ERROR",e.toString());
                error_message = "EX ERROR";
            }
            if(error_message!=null){
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error_message,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

Once the client is connected, I call the `SocketServerListenToMessage` to start listening to client message.

The below code is for `SocketServerListenToMessage`.

```
private class SocketServerListenToMessage extends Thread{
        Socket theClientSocket;
        SocketServerListenToMessage(Socket clientSocketListener){
            theClientSocket = clientSocketListener;
            Log.w("SERVER STATUS","Starting to Listen to Clients...");
        }
        @Override
        public void run(){
            try{
                InputStream is = theClientSocket.getInputStream();
                while(true){
                    byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];
                    is.read(lenBytes, 0, 4);
                    int len = (((lenBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24) | ((lenBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16) |
                           ((lenBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (lenBytes[0] & 0xff));
                    byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[len];
                    is.read(receivedBytes, 0, len);
                    final String received = new String(receivedBytes, 0, len);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Client Says: " + received, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.w("Client Says", received);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("IO ERR FROM LISTEN MSG", e.toString());
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("EX ERR FROM LISTEN MSG", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

With the above code, I can connect multiple client. I can also receive the `Message` from my client. But the problem is I am able to receive a message only from the `First Client that is become connected to my Server`. The `second` and `soon` client was not.

The below code is for my `Client` to `Send Message`. Note I am using `C#` for my client.

```
IPEndPoint serverAddress;
Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);  //I am using Socket

/*********To Send Message to Server**********/

String toSend = txt_v.Text; //The message came from TextBox.
Task f = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
     if (clientSocket.Connected)
     {
       int toSendLen = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetByteCount(toSend);
       byte[] toSendBytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
       byte[] toSendLenBytes = System.BitConverter.GetBytes(toSendLen);
       clientSocket.Send(toSendLenBytes);
       clientSocket.Send(toSendBytes);

      }
});
```

I think the problem is in `while loop` in `SocketServerListenToMessage`. I tried to remove the `while loop` and the Server was able to receive the message from all client but it's only one message per client. I want the Server to listen to client's message until they become disconnected. How can I do that?

Comment: You ran into the "standard Java read problem" `is.read(buffer)` reads **up to the size of the buffer** but it is not guaranteed (if e.g. the TCP data stream stalls you onl may get only 1 byte). If you want to read a complete `byte[]` for sure use a DataInputStream and it's method `readFully(..)`.

Comment: @Robert - I'm sorry, I am not that good in Java, Can you be more specific or at least show an example of code? Thank you and I really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just make it work. Thanks to this [Link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html).

If I'm not mistaken, from the [link](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-multithreaded-servers/multithreaded-server.html), I am using a **singlethreaded**. So from my `SocketServerThread` I have to change

```
SocketServerListenToMessage socketServerListenToMessage = new SocketServerListenToMessage(socket); 
                    socketServerListenToMessage.run();// Start to Receive now
```

to

```
new Thread(new SocketServerListenToMessage(socket)).start();
```

and change the class `SocketServerListenToMessage` to

```
private class SocketServerListenToMessage implements Runnable {
        protected Socket clientSocket = null;

        public SocketServerListenToMessage(Socket clientSocket) {
            this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true){
                    InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                    byte[] lenBytes = new byte[4];
                    is.read(lenBytes, 0, 4);
                    int len = (((lenBytes[3] & 0xff) << 24) | ((lenBytes[2] & 0xff) << 16) |
                            ((lenBytes[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (lenBytes[0] & 0xff));
                    byte[] receivedBytes = new byte[len];
                    is.read(receivedBytes, 0, len);
                    final String received = new String(receivedBytes, 0, len);

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Client Says: " + received, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.w("Client Says", received);

                        }
                    });
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("IO ERR FROM LISTEN MSG", e.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("EX ERR FROM LISTEN MSG", e.toString());
            } finally {
                try{
                    clientSocket.close();
                    Log.w("CLIENT DISCONNECTED", "A client is disconnected.");
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Log.w("IO ERR DISCONNECTION", e.toString());
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I just need to `implement Runnable` instead of `Thread` to make it `Multi`.